# Помогите определиться с версией Vue 3 vs Vue 2

Tags: vue.js

начинаю разработку  проекта в продакшн , Фреймворк для разработки выбран Vue.
Не могу   определиться с версией  3 или 2.
Склоняюсь  больше  ко второй  версии.
С 3  когда работал в последний раз  была сыровата ,  большое  кол-во библиотек не работали.
Интересует момент  как  дела обстоят на  текущий  период времени.
И какую версию выбрали бы  вы.

Comment: Ответом предполагается перечень ***всех*** библиотек экосистемы Vue с пометкой "поддерживает v3"/"не поддерживает v3"?

Comment: @yar85, Вопрос же ясно написан, какую версию выбрали бы вы

Comment: Полагаю, я бы выбрал наиболее свежую стабильную версию. Если есть негативный опыт, можно выбрать вторую версию, так сохраните себе нервы

Comment: Если бы вoпрос был написан ясно (без ненужного описания личных переживаний, и фрагмента "...большое кол-во библиотек не работали. Интересует момент как дела обстоят на текущий период времени") - то конечно, уточнений не потребовалось бы. Но увы...

Comment: К ознакомлению: [Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Вопрос ссылается на опыт использования  Vue3 и  Vue2 ответа "Ввели командную разработку на Vue3 - рекомендую" либо  "на мой взгляд vue3 - сыроват , на мой взгляд надо еще подождать" вполне хватило.  Еще раз @yar85 не нравится  вопрос - не отвечай. По теме от тебя  пользы ноль.

Comment: Еще раз: вoпрос беспредметный, ни о чем, и предполагает соответствующие ответы - поэтому, их тут не дается: разработчики с опытом, это люди рассудительные... с чего им отвечать на абстрактные вопросы исключающие участие рассудка в выборе? Будь тут хоть общее описание проекта, можно было бы предполагать какие библиотеки в нем будут использоваться - и на базе этого ответить. Но этого нет, есть только настойчивые капризы "хочу мнений с потолка" - в этом нет ничего от программирования, планирования, да и в целом от здравой практической логики. Почему бы не подумать об этом и улучшить вoпрос?

Comment: Спасибо ,  хватило ответа Sergey K. ,  @yar85 а вы на программиста не сильно смахиваешь, рассуждения никакого, только одно нытье "не корректно задан вопрос" - попроси уточнить момент который тебе не ясен ,  вы видно человек который заходит на StackOwerflow только для пустословия. Всего вам , старайтесь такие темы  пропускать мимо глаз, а то затопите ядом  и себя и других.

Comment: _«попроси уточнить момент который тебе не ясен»_ - см. самый первый комментарий. Если посмотреть следующие комментарии, то пустословие вместо улучшения вопроса (исходя из рациональных и обоснованных замечаний к нему, включая [отсылку к нормам ресурса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)) тут исходило как раз от тебя. Это лишь сухие факты которые могут что-то прояснить и помочь в личном росте, но если тебе удобнее воспринимать их нерационально/по-детски (в обиду твоей персоне), то я совсем не против этого: твое дело, решать только тебе. Удачи!

Comment: @yar85, если мы перешли на "ты" то -  иди ты лесом. Тебя никто не просил давать мне замечания. Ознакомься сам со своим первым комментарием пойми что он не несет никакой смысловой нагрузки и  успокойся , научись общаться и , а не ядом брызгать в тех кто задает вопрос,  потом прикрываться "рациональным  замечаниями ".Может после этого люди начнут прислушиваться к тебе . Это мой совет тебе, прислушаться или нет  твой выбор. Удачи :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была выбрана версия Vue3.
Если верить источникам Vue2 будет поддерживаться еще пару лет из-за чего придется долгоиграющие проекты в любом случае проект переписывать на 3 версию.
Vue 3 новее, быстрее, меньше весит если ваш проект не завязан на ui kit то я бы выбрал 3 версию.

Comment: На вью 3 тоже есть ui-kit'ы. А так вы правы, в общем-то. Еще огромный плюс именно третьей версии - намного лучшая поддержка TS.